# Upload image to server and save the path in mysql database using php

Tags: mysql, image, upload, path, save

Am new to PHP. Can anyone provide me some sample codes to upload images to server folder and save the path in mysql db. I know how to upload image to server using PHP but i have no idea how to save the images to the the server folder and also save the respective image path to mysql db to get the JSON response. Thanks in advance.